# Subversion: Can I checkout, modify, and then make it a branch?

Tags: svn, branch, svn-checkout

I did a checkout from my trunk to a local DIR and made lots of local changes there. Now I don't want to commit it back to the trunk, but I'd rather make a branch from this local version. Is that possible?

Can I just copy the trunk to a branch, and then `cd DIR` and `svn switch` to the branch?

**UPDATE**: Thanks for the answers, it worked! To summarize the steps:

- `cd DIR`
- `svn copy . new-branch-URL`
- `svn switch new-branch-URL .`

(note the dots)

Comment: yes you can. I use tortoiseSVN and you can do it in that.

Comment: I found too many conflict by using `svn switch`, so I chose to checkout the fresh copy from `new-branch-URL` after `svn copy`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to its command line help svn copy can copy from a directory to a repository URL. So you should be able to copy your working copy to the branch, e.g.:

```
svn copy working_directory url_to_branch
```

Answer (score 52):

The SVN Book (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create) doesn't recommend creating a branch from the local working copy.

> While it's also possible to create a branch by using `svn copy` to duplicate a directory within the working copy, this technique isn't recommended. It can be quite slow, in fact! Copying a directory on the client side is a linear-time operation, in that it actually has to duplicate every file and subdirectory within that working copy directory on the local disk.

Instead, create the branch first and then use the `svn switch` command so you can commit your changes. If your working copy is significantly out of date with the trunk then append "@REV" to the source URL where "REV" is the revision of your working copy reported by `svn info`.

> Copying a directory on the server, however, is a constant-time operation, and it's the way most people create branches.

```
$ svn copy http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk \
           http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch \
      -m "Creating a private branch of /calc/trunk."
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is the better solution as it maintains the revision history.

Comment: Does that mean if I had changes in my local working copy, I could do `svn copy <trunk-URL> <newBranch-URL>` to copy the trunk to a new branch on the svn server, then use `svn switch` in my working copy to switch to the new branch without losing any changes? Or would the switch kill my uncommitted modified files?

Comment: @Kasapo, yes that's right. and also note if you're out of date with the trunk; if so, add "@REV" to the source URL as I noted so that after you switch to the branch only your local changes show up as differences.

Comment: Let me just add a very useful link that explains in more detail Lucas' solution: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.switchwc.html (look at the informative box on the bottom). This is indeed the cleanest and most convenient solution to create a branch from local modifications.

Answer (score 9):

In my SVN client: TortoiseSVN it is enough to:

- right click on the top directory I want to branch
- in "To URL" select the branch directory in your repository
- in the frame "Create copy in the repository from:" select "Working copy"

done :)

It is just like copying local version to specified repository url.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by **SVN commandline** as well as **tortoiseSVN**.

You have to specify your SVN workingcopy as src and your new branch as destination of the

```
svn copy <file/path/to/working/copy> <URL/TO/REPOSITORY/BRANCH>
```

command.

In TortoiseSVN just point into your working copy, choose "Branch/tag" from contextmenu and choose "Working copy" in  the section "Create copy in the repository from:"

Note that it is not a good idea (for traceability reasons )to create tags in such a way, but for branches it is perfectly fine.